# Does Acrobat Acroform support internal small database and export to text features?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, acrobat

I want to create a editable pdf, using Acroform Technology, with the following features, so I would like to know if is it possible before I start diving into learning it:

1 - I want that the javascript script can read some small database (I mean, data hidden inside de pdf document). So, for example, if the user write in a textbox "Silvia", javascript can brings the Silvia's sallary that is in a sallary table hidden inside the pdf.

2 - From pushing a button, javascript script can export to a text file some data that is inside the pdf (from form elements and databases inside de pdf).

Is both features possible using Acroform?

Comment: Yes... but the script will only run in Adobe Acrobat, Reader, and maybe Foxit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature 1 is no problem; you may work with arrays, and then convert them to strings you can put in (hidden) fields for saving and reopening the document.

Feature 2 will most likely require Acrobat (Pro), as there are still some limitations in Reader.

Comment: Thanks Max! I can't believe I didn't thought about it (create huge "data arrays" inside my script). Thanks for the tip :) Do you think that, instead of export data to a text file (Feature 2), I could send data to clipboard? If so, that would works as well for my needs.